# Animating with CSS - Alternatives to String Concatenation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, game-engine

I'm working on a game in Javascript, using `<canvas>` elements. I've read that it's more efficient to use CSS-based animations due to possible hardware acceleration. Using the CSS attribute `.style.transform`, is an alternative to animating an element by setting it's `.style.top` and `.style.left` attributes. Another possible alternative is drawing shapes / images on a single `<canvas>` and using `context.drawImage(canvas, x, y);` (i.e. animating with Javascript).

I've done a lot of testing, and I've already profiled the software animation with Javascript. I'm now attempting to profile the CSS-based (possibly) hardware-accelerated animation.

My problem is this: **Using CSS to animate requires setting (element.style.transform), which is a string.**

My question is this: **What is the most efficient way to set that string, the form of which looks like:** `element.style.transform = "translate("+(x)+"px, "+(y)+"px)";` **?**

Possibilities include:

1. Concatenate the string with the desired x, y, values each frame, for all sprites
2. Hash a discrete (approximated) list of x, y, values to string values, perform an approximation of the inputs, set `element.style.transform` to the lookup of the hash table
3. Memoize used x, y, values and corresponding string values
4. **Your Input Here**

Current Code:

```
var x = 0, y = 0;

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;
}

function loop() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    objCanvas.style.transform = "translate("+(x)+"px, "+(y)+"px)";
}

loop();
```

Thank you ahead of time for any given input.

Comment: I don't think a number to string conversion will be the bottleneck of your code.

Comment: @Oriol you are almost certainly correct sir. My question is mainly academic in nature, and it always bothers me to have to slap `+ "px"` on the end of the line.

Comment: I most certainly wouldn't worry about it, and it probably differs a little from engine to engine (you would have to test). What I would say is that, if I was targeting ES6 then I would use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), they make it look a little nicer (no idea about performance)

Comment: Well that solves at least one problem @Xotic750 , thanks!

Comment: i would pre-define all the positions with incremental classes, then change the class on the element insted of the style. this lets the layout engine become aware of the rules earlier, which could decrease application time, and gives you a nice place to add additional rules without doubling complexity.

Comment: @dandavis There will always be 800*600 different possible positions or more (unless route 2 is taken, which would decrease the number by a factor of whatever granularity I choose), which doesn't seem feasible to pre-define as a list of classes.. Is that what you meant? Also, how would setting the `element.className` be more efficient than setting the `element.style.transform` ? (other than the obvious, one less drill down) ?

Comment: `ctx.drawImage()` is hardware accelerated and is a lot quicker then updating the CSS rules and manipulating the DOM every 60th of a second.